# recompile VC++ 6 code for X64 plateform

Tags: visual-c++, 64-bit

I have an old VC++ 6 code compiled as DLL, I used it for many years without problems, now i need it in a x64 application, can i recompile the old code to produce a X64 DLL?
Am I need the same VC++ 6 IDE or another compiler?

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately, the answer to both of your questions is: maybe.

I have had good luck taking VC++ source code for old 32-bit DLLs and recompiling it for 64-bit. Sometimes it is a simple recompile. Other times, minor adjustments have to be made. My biggest concern would be if the 32-bit DLL relies on other 32-bit DLLs that you may not have source code for. In that case, unless you have 64-bit copies of the other DLLs, you are probably out of luck.

Now, I have never tried to do this with VC++ 6. I've done it with Visual Studio 2010. However, the windows platform SDK used to support compiling for 64-bit with VC6. My understanding is that the last version of the SDK that supported this was the February 2003 version. I just checked MSDN and I do not see this available for download. That doesn't mean you cannot get a copy (and you may already have one). It does mean that getting a copy won't be as easy as going to MSDN and downloading it.

Now, having said that, my recommendation is to use a newer compiler to make your 64-bit DLL. Assuming Windows, all recent Visual Studio compilers (2008, 2010, 2012) will do 64-bit, provided you've installed the 64-bit tools.